# coniure-up canonical kubernetes never ends

Tags: conjure-up

I'm trying conjure-up with "The canonical distribution of Kubernetes"

After 5 hours the process is not eneded.

8 lxd machine are in active state but the "etc/2" machine remains in waiting.
From juju status command I see:

etcd/2                    waiting   allocating  3        172.16.0.206                    waiting for machine

What can I do?

Comment: Are you running this inside VMware or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat resolved: trying the install from scratch in a new VM ended correctly using ubuntu 16.04 and conjure-up snap updated to 11 March 2017